# Javascript doesn't work in ionic template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have different html template files in my ionic project.  Those are something link

```
$stateProvider
.state('home', {
  url: '/',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  controller: 'HomeController'
})
```

Javascript works in the html file (`index.html`) which includes `home.html`, but doesn't work in `home.html`

```
<ion-view title="Home">
  <ion-content>
    <script type="text/javascript">console.log('abc')</script>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Please post more code.

Comment: It is completely wrong to use javascript code in ionic view file. But if you want to use put js code as first line or last line in ionic view file and it should work.

Comment: @Rahul , can you explain more why it's completely wrong to use javascript code in ionic view file?

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS doesn't support this. Include jQuery on your page and then angularjs and it should work. See https://groups.google.com/d/topic/angular/H4haaMePJU0/discussion

Answer (score 0):

`<ion-content></ion-content>` Is part of ng-view changes without reloading the page.

The only way you have to add your script src in main `index.html` page, **or** ask directly about the function you want to find better way to organize your code